# Distribution of the parsing task to several servers

Tags: xml, parsing

I have a task to write an application that will parse tens or hundreds of gigabytes of xml every day and write the result to a relational DBMS. I have several servers available for this task. The question is how do I distribute tasks to several machines. Do I need to turn to technologies like Apache Kafka or Apache Hadoop? What are the alternatives to these technologies?

Comment: Hundreds of GB still fits on a single common HDD. It's still not considered "big data"

Comment: Yes, I think this tag is probably superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`spark-xml`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) library, with or without Hadoop or Kafka.

Spark can also write to relational databases.

You could use Airflow to schedule Spark jobs.